# Why are my xml and gradle and value files changing themselves?

Tags: android

I code something in android studio and it works. 
I closed the program and when i open it again the project  is filled with errors and its files (the ones mentioned in the headline) have changed  completely which  it can not run the code itself. Sometimes i even get things that are not even ASCII characters. 
In the code itself(Java) i can no longer create `TextInputEditText`.

Well for the gradles i have created a new project and copied the gradles from those and put them there. 
For the drawables i had to re-upload them, re-convert them to PNG (although they already were) and  i had to re-write `xmls`.

I just need to know what's causing such malfunction.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, whenever you open a code in Android Studio, maybe you are clicking on upgrading Gradle version, and it changes some gradle files.
And you need to add your drawables manually to the GIT and make sure those are uploaded, to the repo, make sure your .gitignore does not include PNG.

What I would say, is open virtual box, install a fresh Ubuntu system and Android stack with Android Studio. Now git clone your repo, and upgrade your gradle and all the build.gradle dependencies. Now remove all those ASCII characters. Also make sure, your keyboard language is US English and generally the OS is also in English.